# Create a function without the [[Construct]] internal method, but that can be bound

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function object without the `[[Construct]]` internal method, but that can be bound.

Is this the only way to do it?

```js
const { foo } = ({ foo() { console.log(this.name) } })
const bar = foo.bind({ name: 'bar' })
bar() // 'bar'
new bar() // 'Uncaught TypeError: bar is not a constructor'
```

Comment: Do class methods behave similarly?

Comment: Yes, identically.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Dang, I was writing the answer, but had to learn (or be reminded) from trincot’s answer that async functions are also not constructable. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you suggest is surely the most straightforward way to do it.

If you are not interested in the value that the function returns, you can also define your function as `async`.

```js
const foo = async function() { console.log(this.name) };
const bar = foo.bind({ name: 'bar' });
bar(); // 'bar'
new bar(); // 'Uncaught TypeError: bar is not a constructor'
```